# IE Window close issue with linkedin javascript SDK

Tags: linkedin-api

I am using the sign in with LinkedIn javascript SDK on a site. However, some IE and Edge users are experiencing an issue with the login popup. Instead of seeing the login screen, they get a window that says "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the window. Do you want to close this window? Yes/No".

If yes is clicked, the window closes. If no is clicked, there is a 404 error.

I believe this has something to do with IE/Edge security and privacy settings or, the SDK may be calling a close() function without an open().

Maybe the linkedIn SDK needs to be edited or, is there a way for me to check for the security settings with js prior to showing the login with LinkedIn button?

Has anyone experience this?

[image: screenshot of window]

[image: 404 page]